# How to setup mysql database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am new  laravel programmer, and I have simple question 
about setting up database.

Assume that I create all required migrations, models, and eloquent relationships, also configure mysql database in laravel, now in this point, is laravel will create all mysql tables required in server's DB according to migrations, models, and eloquent that I created before?
In other words, do I need to create tables in mysql server as scratch developer do?

Comment: When you run `php artisan migrate` the databases will be created and populated with any data you have specified [See](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel have many commands from console.

from console,go to your project folder path run `php artisan list` to see all avaliable commands.

your question asked how to create tables after you created migrations, which is `php artisan migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

To create a migration, use the `make:migration` Artisan command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

To run all of your outstanding migrations, execute the `migrate` Artisan command:

```
php artisan migrate
```